# How to iterate over different variables/states to create an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects, react-hooks

I need help iterating over variables/state elements to create an object. I am going to iterate over firstName state, lastName state, and many more states. The code is getting way too complicated. Was wondering if there is a proper way to build an object for a graphql call? or just a better way to build an object?

I have a profile page that has forms for updating the user's account. Each form input has state and setState props. On submit of the form these values need to be checked against the previous queried information stored in the account object stored in state. I am using a graphql endpoint and when I call make the update account call, I have 3 choices for each parameter value in the graphql call For example, firstName can be 
1) Null (delete in database) 
2) Some non-null value (change to this value in database) 
3) field does not exist in call graphql call (do nothing to that attribute)
The code below I have to do for 20 state values which is not practical.

```
// If there is a difference between client's firstName and queried firstName in server
if (firstName != account.firstName) {
  //If we stored firstName as empty String
  if(firstName === ''){ 
    //If the firstName queried is not empty
    if(account.firstName != null) {
      //Set the objects first name attribute to null, so server deletes field
      input['firstName'] = null;
    } else {
      //firstName is empty string and server value is null, so do nothing, do not add attribute firstName to object "input"
    }
  } else {
    //firstName is not an empty string so add it to object value
    input['firstName'] = firstName;
  }
}
```

If there is a better way to do this I would love the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way around it is to use the bracket notation to extract specify the `key` for which you want to extract the value and the value that it needs to be checked against.

```js
function getComputedValue(value, key) {
  if (value != account[key]) {
    if (value === '') {
      if (account[key] != null) {
        input[key] = null;
      } else {
        
      }
    } else {
      input[key] = value;
    }
  }
}

let firstName = getComputedValue("Tom", "firstName");
let lastName = getComputedValue("Smith", "lastName");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can approach this problem. I suggest you use some of the functions [Underscore JS](https://underscorejs.org/#pairs) provides :

`pairs_.pairs(object)`

Convert an object into a list of `[key, value]` pairs. The opposite of object.

```
_.pairs({one: 1, two: 2, three: 3});
=> [["one", 1], ["two", 2], ["three", 3]]
```

Then you can iterate through the array

```
_.each(array, function(pair) {
// Insert the input assignment code here for each key  
});
```